# How to group rows in htmldatatable?

Tags: java, jsf, htmldatatable

How to group rows in htmldatatable?
I am using JSF.

A short example :

```
TransNum   TransAmount   InvoiceNum   InvoiceAmount

   1                50          1              10  
   1                50          2              15
   1                50          3              30
   2                10          1               6
   2                10          2               5
```

If I select Grouping column as "InvoiceNum" then the table should look like:-
(i.e Grouping is done on InvoiceNum):

```
TransNum   TransAmount   InvoiceNum   InvoiceAmount
                               1
  1                50          1              10         
  2                10          1               6
                               2
  1                50          2              15
  2                10          2               5
                               3
  1                50          3              30
```

TransNum   TransAmount   InvoiceNum   InvoiceAmount
Similarly, grouping can be done based on multiple columns values too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of jsf are you using?  Can you explain your scenerio in more detail?

Comment: I am using JSF 1.2. I need to display the data in the table in a group based on the column. The rows will be grouped in based on the column values.

Answer (score 2):

JSF `h:dataTable` has no built-in grouping.

Either you find a component that fits your needs in one of the component libraries, such as [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf), [Richfaces](http://exadel.com/web/portal/richfacesdemo) or [Icefaces](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface).

Or you have to implement it yourself in the backing bean by sorting the list in the way you want.

Comment: I too would recommend RichFaces.  With a small number of columns like the example you could write nested html tables inside one column of your datatable.  It is messy and hard to read but is an option.